# Checking the duplicate field value on the blur event of the dynamic field in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Add Car Name loads new input text with empty value;

Entering the duplicate car name gets validated against the list. But, the issue I am facing is the ng-model is getting the updated value/entered value each time and on-blur it is filtering/searching against the same value and throwing the error.

DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/D0NpoekJ9intwLT0?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1

HTML:

```
 <ul ng-repeat="cl in cars.list">
        <li>
          <input name="carName{{$index}}" type="text", ng-model="cl.name", ng-blur="checkDuplicateName(cl.name, $index, cars.list)"/>
          <small style="color:red" ng-show="cars.isDuplicate">Duplicate Car Name</small>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

JS:

```
 $scope.checkDuplicateName = function(name,index, carList){
        console.log(carList);
        console.log(name);
        if (carList.filter((cl) => cl.name === name).length) {
          $scope.cars.isDuplicate = true;
          
         // $timeout(function () {
            // $scope.myFrom.['carName' + index].$setValidity("$invalid",true); 
         // });
        }else{
           $scope.cars.isDuplicate = false;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because data is getting updated in the real time for the ngmodel.
while filtering you need to make sure that, it will not consider the current value.
so you can try something like below in ***checkDuplicateName*** function.

```js
 $scope.checkDuplicateName = function(name,currentIndex, carList){
    console.log(carList);
    console.log(name);
    if (carList.filter((cl, index) => currentIndex !== index && cl.name === name).length) {
      $scope.cars.isDuplicate = true;
      $scope.cars.list[index] = { name: '' };
     // $timeout(function () {
        // $scope.myFrom.['carName' + index].$setValidity("$invalid",true); 
     // });
    }else{
       $scope.cars.isDuplicate = false;
    }
  }
```

make use of index and check for `currentIndex !== index`